# Maximum Likelihood for $\beta_1$ Using Partial Derivatives

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Assume $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + e_i$ and $e_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. One way to estimate $\mathbf{\beta}$ is via maximum likelihood estimate. I saw from elsewhere that $\mathbf{\beta}$ could also be estimated using $$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}_{\text{ML}} = \beta_0 - \left( \frac{\partial^2 L} {\partial \mathbf{\beta^2}}\right)^{-1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\beta}},$$ where ML is maximum likelihood and $L$ is the likelihood function. How valid is this? Could anyone give insightful explanation and probably some references on it?

Comment: What is $\beta$? Probably $\beta_1$?

Comment: It cannot be both, IMHO. For me it is still unclear.

Comment: Ok. Consider $\beta_1$

Comment: The source would be helpful. What I have probably found out is that $\sum x_i=0$. But it is completely not sure.

Comment: O.K, here is the problem: Given a two sample model with $\textbf{X}_{N\times 2} = \begin{pmatrix}  \textbf{1}_{n_1}  & \textbf{0} \\ \textbf{1}_{n_2}  & \textbf{1}_{n_2} \end{pmatrix}$. Estimate $\hat{\beta}_1$ using $\hat{\beta}_{ML}$, ${n_1}$ and ${n_2}$ are the respective sample sizes.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's worth pointing out that there are two different meanings for the term $\beta_0$ in the above. There's the coefficients vector $\beta = (\beta_0,\beta_1)$; there's also the initial point $\beta_{0} = (\beta_{0,0},\beta_{0,1})$ in an iterative search for that vector. To avoid confusion, I'll refer to the latter as $\beta_{init}$.

The formula
$$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = \beta_{init} - \left( \frac{\partial^2 L} {\partial \mathbf{\beta^2}}\right)^{-1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\beta}}$$
does not in general give the MLE. However, the same formula applied to the log-likelihood $l$,
$$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}_{ML} = \beta_{init} - \left( \frac{\partial^2 l} {\partial \mathbf{\beta^2}}\right)^{-1} \frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{\beta}}$$
reduces to the standard expression $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ for the MLE, for any value of $\beta_{init}$.

This formula can be recognised as one step of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions) for optimising a function. In general, Newton's method requires many steps to converge; for regression, however, the log-likelihood is quadratic in $\beta$, which means that one step of Newton's method is sufficient.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adam, would you also take a look at above comments for  
callculus42 above?

Comment: The bot message above refers to a previous version of the answer. The answer seems quite clearly written to me now.